# Traefik using SSL/Multiple SNI with mixed authentication

Tags: traefik

In Traefik, is it possible to either:

A.  Setup two different SSL entrypoints, such that I can enable TLS Mutual Authentication on one SNI (ClientCAFiles) and not on the other;

or

B.  Use the same entrypoint (:443), but have the ClientCAFiles directive only apply to a specific URL

I've tried something like this:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
    clientCAFiles = ["certs/clientca.crt"]
    [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "certs/server1.crt"
    keyFile = "certs/server1.key"
  [entrypoints.otherSSL]
  address = ":8443"
  [entryPoints.otherSSL.tls]
    [[entryPoints.otherSSL.tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "certs/server2.crt"
    keyFile = "certs/server2.key"
```

but doesn't work.  Also tried like this:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
    [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
    clientCAFiles = ["certs/clientca.crt"]
    certFile = "certs/server1.crt"
    keyFile = "certs/server1.key"
    [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "certs/server2.crt"
    keyFile = "certs/server2.key"
```

This also does not work.

This works:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
    clientCAFiles = ["certs/clientca.crt"]
    [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "certs/server1.crt"
    keyFile = "certs/server1.key"
    [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "certs/server2.crt"
    keyFile = "certs/server2.key"
```

but requires clientAuth for BOTH SNIs.